# SQL query to change dates during runtime

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I need to write a SQL query to get last 10 years of data. For the first release date require last 10 years data and second release dates are mentioned in the picture. Need to automate dates according to the release date. Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NGKs.png)

For every release date, dates should automatically changes. Should not be hard-coded dates.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as **text** we can copy/paste, not images); a complete description of the problem; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with your solution; and the expected output for the sample data. If you don't tell us what your tables are and only vaguely describe what you expect how are we supposed to provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpfull:

```sql
WITH
    release_dates AS        -- sample data
        (   Select Add_Months(SYSDATE, (-10 + LEVEL)) - (LEVEL * 3) "RELEASE_DATE" From Dual  Connect By LEVEL <= 9 )
SELECT
    RELEASE_DATE,
  --
  ADD_MONTHS(
      CASE WHEN To_Char(RELEASE_DATE, 'dd') <= 20 THEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(RELEASE_DATE, -1))
      ELSE LAST_DAY(RELEASE_DATE)
      END + 1
    , - 120) "START_DATE",
  --
    CASE WHEN To_Char(RELEASE_DATE, 'dd') <= 20 THEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(RELEASE_DATE, -1))
    ELSE LAST_DAY(RELEASE_DATE)
    END "END_DATE",
  --
  To_Char(
      ADD_MONTHS(
          CASE WHEN To_Char(RELEASE_DATE, 'dd') <= 20 THEN LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(RELEASE_DATE, -1))
          ELSE LAST_DAY(RELEASE_DATE)
          END + 1
        , - 120)
  , 'dd-MON-yy') || ' - ' ||
  To_Char(RELEASE_DATE, 'dd-MON-yy')"DATA_REFRESH_DATES"
FROM
    release_dates
```

R e s u l t :

| RELEASE_DATE | START_DATE | END_DATE | DATA_REFRESH_DATES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-MAR-22 | 01-MAR-12 | 28-FEB-22 | 01-MAR-12 - 18-MAR-22 |
| 15-APR-22 | 01-APR-12 | 31-MAR-22 | 01-APR-12 - 15-APR-22 |
| 12-MAY-22 | 01-MAY-12 | 30-APR-22 | 01-MAY-12 - 12-MAY-22 |
| 09-JUN-22 | 01-JUN-12 | 31-MAY-22 | 01-JUN-12 - 09-JUN-22 |
| 06-JUL-22 | 01-JUL-12 | 30-JUN-22 | 01-JUL-12 - 06-JUL-22 |
| 03-AUG-22 | 01-AUG-12 | 31-JUL-22 | 01-AUG-12 - 03-AUG-22 |
| 31-AUG-22 | 01-SEP-12 | 31-AUG-22 | 01-SEP-12 - 31-AUG-22 |
| 27-SEP-22 | 01-OCT-12 | 30-SEP-22 | 01-OCT-12 - 27-SEP-22 |
| 25-OCT-22 | 01-NOV-12 | 31-OCT-22 | 01-NOV-12 - 25-OCT-22 |